# How can I trigger a Docker build as an sbt subproject dependency?

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have a project w/subprojects in sbt.  I build and unit test each subproject.  I want to have a distinct subproject 'integration' where I will do integration tests.  Before running these tests I want to force the build of a Docker image for each subproject.

Using just one subproject as an example I tried this:

```
lazy val msg = project.in(file("msg"))
    .settings(basicSettings: _*)
    .settings(dockerStuff:_*)
    .settings(libraryDependencies ++=
        dep_compile(microcore, akka_cluster, akka_cluster_tools, opencmis, apns, handlebars) ++
        dep_test(scalatest)
    )

lazy val integration = project.in(file("integration"))
    .settings(basicSettings: _*)
    .settings(libraryDependencies ++=
        dep_test(microcore, scalatest)
    )
    .dependsOn(msg % "publishLocal in Docker")
```

This is producing this error:

```
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last integration/*:clean for the full output.
[error] (integration/*:clean) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot add dependency 'com.cof#msg_2.11;0.1_SNAPSHOT' to configuration 'publishLocal in Docker' of module com.cof#integration_2.11;9c2539_SNAPSHOT because this configuration doesn't exist!
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Feb 16, 2016 3:35:18 PM
```

What am I missing?  Is this the correct way to for my integration subproject to trigger/force the Docker build on the msg subproject?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: Create a task defined in msg that builds the Docker images.  Then wire that task to fire on testOnly (or test or whatever) in integration.  Took some fidgeting to get it going but this seems to work.

```
lazy val buildDocker = taskKey[Unit]("Build Dockers")

lazy val msg = project.in(file("msg"))
    .settings(basicSettings: _*)
    .settings(dockerStuff:_*)
        .settings(
            buildDocker in ThisBuild := (publishLocal in Docker).value // ThisBuild exposes dockz to the entire build
            )
    .settings(libraryDependencies ++=
        dep_compile(microcore, akka_cluster, akka_cluster_tools, opencmis, apns, handlebars) ++
        dep_test(scalatest)
    )

lazy val integration = project.in(file("integration"))
    .settings(basicSettings: _*)
    .settings(libraryDependencies ++=
        dep_test(microcore, scalatest)
    )
    .settings((Keys.testOnly in Test) <<= (Keys.testOnly in Test) dependsOn (buildDocker)) // wire testOnly to buildDocker
```